# How to make a button for capitalization in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

How can I change this script so that a user has to click a button at the end to make all form text entries change to capitals? I know that I need to use the `onclick` function, but I am just not sure where or how to enter it.

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Information Form</title>
      <style>
         input[type=text] {
           text-transform: capitalize;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
       <input type="text" name="nameInput" />
       Type your street address here:
       <input type="text" address="addressInput" />

       Type your city and state here:
       <input type="text" cityandstate="stateInput" />
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggest finding a tutorial on JavaScript/HTML. It will help to understand more about valid HTML as well, which you currently do not have.

Comment: `a user has to click a button at the end ` can you please explain this ?

Comment: Script tags are added at the end of the body, or in external .js file and imported in the html file:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Information Form</title>
      <style>
         input[type=text] {
           text-transform: capitalize;
          }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
       <input type="text" name="nameInput" />
       Type your street address here:
       <input type="text" address="addressInput" />

       Type your city and state here:
       <input type="text" cityandstate="stateInput" />

       <div>
    <button id="clickme" onclick="capInputs();">Capitalize Inputs</button>
       </div>

       <script>
        function capInputs() {
               var elements = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")
               for (var i = 0, element; element = elements[i++];) {
                  element.value = (element.value).toUpperCase();
               }
        }
       </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

See this :D

```js
document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", displayDate);

function displayDate() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("myBtn").innerHTML =x.toUpperCase() ;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>

<p>This example uses the addEventListener() method to attach a click event to a button.</p>

<button id="myBtn">Try it</button>





</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to force the user to click a button at the end to change their text to uppercase. You can do this authomatically using JavaScript.

It looks like you've figured out that using CSS won't change the `value` of your inputs to uppercase, only change the appearance on the screen (and on my browser, `text-transform` doesn't even seem to work on the `input` element). Instead, you should attach event listeners to your the `input` event (which is fired every time input text is edited) inside a `<script>...</script>` tag (which should be inserted just before the closing `</body>` tag.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(e) {
  if (e.type === 'text') {
    e.addEventListener('input', valueToUpperCase)
  }
})

function valueToUpperCase(e) {
  (e = e.target).value = e.value.toUpperCase()
}
```

```html
<label>
  Type your name here:
  <input type="text" name="nameInput" />
</label>
<br/>
<label>
  Type your street address here:
  <input type="text" name="addressInput" />
</label>
<br/>
<label>
  Type your city and state here:
  <input type="text" name="stateInput" />
  </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming (based on your css rule) that you want to capitalize the input text entries once the user press a button. If you want to change all text into upper case (i.e. all capital letters, not just the first one), then uppercase should be used in the css instead of capitalize.

@Amber Ollis, your code applies the CSS rule for capitalize to all input text elements from the beginning. The rule should only apply once pressed the button if that is the effect you want (I have added such button which is missing in your code).

See code below (working):

```
<html>
  <head> 
    <title>Information Form</title>
      <style>
        .capitalized {
           text-transform: capitalize;
          }
      </style>
       <script>
     function capitalize() {
       var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]");
       for (i in inputs) {
           inputs[i].className = "capitalized";
       }
     }
       </script>

  </head>
  <body>
       <input type="text" name="nameInput" />
       Type your street address here:
       <input type="text" address="addressInput" />

       Type your city and state here:
       <input type="text" cityandstate="stateInput" />

       <input type="button" onclick="capitalize();" value="Capitalize all" />

   </body>
</html>
```